# How to pass an array from ajax to code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a array of string myArray[] in my jQuery the value is generated dynamically. I also have a method in my code behind that has string[] myArray.

I am using the following code in my jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "myurl/MyMethod",
  data: "{'strArray' :" + myArray + ", 'id':" + x + "}",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response){
  // DO SOME STUFF WITH THE RESPONSE...
  }
});
```

I have the following in my code behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool MyMethod(string[] strArray, int id)
{
  // DO SOME STUFF WITH THE PARAMETERS
}
```

Now the issue is the ajax is not calling MyMethod. Any points...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post the error you are getting, also please post what, data actually looks like.

Comment: @Maess
myArray is a array of strings. example can be...
myArray[] = {'string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3'}

Comment: "code behind" = "server-side code" or "server-side script".

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot
"code behind" = "Server-Side Code"

Comment: @mahfuz01, yes I know. In the interest of clarity, I'm respectfully suggesting you use the correct terminology.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, thanks for your suggestion. I am a newbie to ASP .NET. sorry for the inconvenience caused. btw, the issue is been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue resolved...

the array of strings from jQuery can be read as a whole string at the code behind. example:

```
var myArray[] = {"string 1", "string 2", "string 3"};
```

will be

```
string myValue = "string 1,string 2,string 3";
```

in the serverside code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myParam = {'strArray' : myArray, 'id' : x };

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "myurl/MyMethod",
  data: $.param(myParam),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response){
  // DO SOME STUFF WITH THE RESPONSE...
  }
});
```

If you are using MVC, and your input elements match the values you are passing back, you can just serialize all the inputs: `data: $('form').serialize(),`